# Find multiline blocks of text in R and R-Studio using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, r

I was quite good at using regular expressions in PHP, but now I've completely stuck with a new programming language R. 
An example of the working code is here https://regex101.com/r/mO1yR3/2
What I want to do, is to find and replace block of texts containing (Mini) at the header. Just delete those blocks from the text and save it to a file.

I spent a day finding the solution and I'am on a brink to dump R. It's much faster to do it in PHP, Perl or Python.
The code I used for R:

```
library(readr)
library(stringr)
contentsTosCSV <- read_file("d:/ProVallue/Provalue Group/BackTesting/SPY/2015/test.txt")
contentsTosCSV <- str_replace_all(contentsTosCSV, '\\r', '')#deleting \r 
matches <- grep('|(^.*\\(Mini\\)(?s).*?\\n\\n)|mg', contentsTosCSV, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)
print(matches)
```

It matches the whole string in contentsTosCSV 
Then I tried these:

```
matches <- grep('(?m)(^.*\\(Mini\\)(?s).*?\\n\\n)', contentsTosCSV, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)
print(matches)
```

and substituting the m modifyer with [.\n] with (?m) and (?s) and without.

```
matches <- grep('(^.*\\(Mini\\)[.\\n]*?\\n\\n)', contentsTosCSV, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)
print(matches)
```

example text:

```
Last,Net Chng,Volume,Open,High,Low
209.79,-.71,"113,965,728",210.46,210.53,208.65

JUL4 15  (-10)  100 (Weeklys)
,,Mark,Last,Delta,Impl Vol,Open.Int,Volume,Bid,Ask,Exp,Strike,Bid,Ask,Mark,Last,Delta,Impl Vol,Open.Int,Volume,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

SEP 15  (46)  100
,,Mark,Last,Delta,Impl Vol,Open.Int,Volume,Bid,Ask,Exp,Strike,Bid,Ask,Mark,Last,Delta,Impl Vol,Open.Int,Volume,,
,,129.790,127.28,1.00,0.00%,0,0,129.55,129.87,SEP 15,80,0,.01,.005,.01,.00,81.60%,"2,964",0,,
,,.005,.01,.00,14.71%,"4,563",0,0,.01,SEP 15,245,36.19,36.52,36.355,0,-.94,27.65%,0,0,,
,,.005,.02,.00,16.54%,"2,473",0,0,.01,SEP 15,250,41.19,41.49,41.340,38.87,-.94,30.20%,118,0,,

SEP 15  (46)  10 (Mini)
,start,Mark,Last,Delta,Impl Vol,Open.Int,Volume,Bid,Ask,Exp,Strike,Bid,Ask,Mark,Last,Delta,Impl Vol,Open.Int,Volume,,
,,20.165,15.70,.91,21.64%,1,0,17.75,22.58,SEP 15,190,.52,4.99,2.755,2.22,-.19,32.90%,26,0,,
,,19.165,0,.91,20.79%,0,0,16.80,21.53,SEP 15,191,0,4.99,2.495,0,-.19,30.53%,0,0,,
,,18.230,21.31,.90,20.46%,2,0,15.83,20.63,SEP 15,192,0,4.99,2.495,2.90,-.19,29.45%,6,0,,end

SEP5 15  (58)  100 (Quarterlys)
,,Mark,Last,Delta,Impl Vol,Open.Int,Volume,Bid,Ask,Exp,Strike,Bid,Ask,Mark,Last,Delta,Impl Vol,Open.Int,Volume,,
,,134.790,132.33,1.00,0.00%,0,0,134.54,134.88,SEP5 15,75,0,.02,.010,.01,.00,81.69%,"2,375",0,,
,,129.790,127.37,1.00,0.00%,0,0,129.54,129.88,SEP5 15,80,0,.02,.010,.01,.00,76.86%,620,0,,

OCT 15  (74)  100
,,Mark,Last,Delta,Impl Vol,Open.Int,Volume,Bid,Ask,Exp,Strike,Bid,Ask,Mark,Last,Delta,Impl Vol,Open.Int,Volume,,
,,73.790,0,1.00,0.00%,0,0,73.56,73.89,OCT 15,136,.01,.03,.020,0,.00,33.93%,0,0,,
,,72.790,0,1.00,0.00%,0,0,72.57,72.89,OCT 15,137,.01,.03,.020,0,.00,33.35%,0,0,,
,,71.790,0,1.00,0.00%,0,0,71.57,71.89,OCT 15,138,.01,.04,.025,.04,.00,33.54%,300,0,,
,,70.790,0,1.00,0.00%,0,0,70.57,70.90,OCT 15,139,.02,.04,.030,0,.00,33.62%,0,0,,
```

Comment: Please include a clear question.

Answer (score 1):

I've based on your regex101 sample and modified your regex by doing the `[\s\S]` trick.

You can use a regex like this:

```
(\(Mini\)[\s\S]*?end)
```

Here you can find the update:

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/mO1yR3/3)**

Comment: Both `matches <- grep('((?m)^.*\\(Mini\\)[\\s\\S]*?end)', contentsTosCSV, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE, fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)
print(matches)` and your variant `(\(Mini\)[\s\S]*?end)` select the whole text from the very begining to the end in R-Studio.

Comment: Screw R. Actually, I turned to R to finish my research in matlab. I heard many people say R + Python is better. I liked R, but regular expressions in R is a pain in the a...  The code which solved my problem in matlab was:  
`new_str = regexprep(wholeFile, '\r', '', 'lineanchors');  
new_str = regexprep(new_str, '^[\w\d\.,\-\"% _\(\)]*?\(Mini\)[\w\d\.,\-\"% _\(\)\n{1}]*?\n\n', '', 'lineanchors');  
new_str = regexprep(new_str, '\n', '\r\n');`

Comment: @AndrewMakarskiy thanks for the comment, you should post your answer and mark your question as resolved

Comment: The problem is not resolved, since I still have not found a solution in R. Now it is getting kind of a chellange to R coders